# Extend module using class syntax, not prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class, oop

The `gm` node module mentions in its documentation that you can use `.prototype` syntax to extend the classes functionality.

https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/wiki/Extending-gm

```
var gm = require("gm")
gm.prototype.sepia = function(){
  this.modulate(115, 0, 100).colorize(7, 21, 50)
  return this
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way using TypeScript, to extend this using class syntax?

When I try to do it the obvious way I get this error:

> Type 'typeof import("/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/interactive-stitch/node_modules/@types/gm/index.d.ts")' is not a constructor function type.ts(2507)

```
import gm from 'gm'
class Magick extends gm {}
```

Comment: The code you show appears to work in regular Javascript (when I tried something similar) so you probably need type info for `gm` that tells TypeScript that `gm` is a constructor and what its arguments and methods are.  This is the rub with TypeScript.  You can't just freely reference symbols (unless you genericize them) - you have to have previously told TypeScript all about the objects you're trying to use so it knows all the typing info about them.

Comment: I assume  you're already seen the `.subclass()` method that `gm` has and  you're trying to avoid using that?

Comment: FYI, type definitions for the gm library appear to be here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gm